# Excel - Can't Extract Partial String via known formulas

Tags: excel, string, replace, formula

I know this has been beaten to death but I cannot get mine to work for the below example:

%B1234567^SMITH/MIKE^ABC123DEF456?;1234567=0111000?

A1 contains the above text data and I am trying to copy the string between "%B" and the first "^".
I tried:

```
=mid(left(A1,find("%B",A1)-1),find("^",A1)+1,len(A1))
```

But no data appears in B1 (where the formula is placed).
Any suggestions?

Thanks, Brendan

Comment: is `%B` always at the beginning of the string? It the string to be extracted always a seven digit number? It may be worthwhile to provide a more representative sample of your data

Comment: I am trying to extract the name with:

=MID(LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-1),FIND("^",B2)+1,LEN(B2))

It produces SMITH/MIKE as it should.  However, when I change the blank space in the first FIND to the "^", it does not produce a value.  Headscratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("%B",A1)+2,FIND("^",A1,FIND("%B",A1))-FIND("%B",A1)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and try:

```
=mid(A1,find("B",A1,1)+1,6)*1
```

You can then incorporate the extra code to find the caret if needed, as I assumed 7 digits or characters. To get the result recognized as a number multiply by 1.

Just don't use the %

[image]

Comment: The issue with that formula, as you stated, we are assuming the known length of the number which can vary.  I was able to get it to work with the MID but how do I get the search in the formula to use two characters such as the "%B".  Also, I need to go to the 2nd "^" in my search parameter.
/
GOOD:     =MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("^",A2)-1),FIND("B",A2)+1,LEN(A2)), pulls the 1234567
/
I need to pull the ABC123DEF456 but if I use the above formula with the "^", it returns:
/
SMITH/MIKE^ABC123DEF456, this is where I need it to go to the 2nd "^" so I don't get the name.

Comment: @The_BK_Man that was my point, you don't need the %  symbol, just the B. As for finding the second caret, you can do find("^",A1,find("^",A1,1)+1)

Comment: Now let's say I have a space after the name and before the ^ symbol:
%B1234567^SMITH/MIKE  ^ABC123DEF456?;1234567=0111000?
I can extract the name with:   
=MID(LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-1),FIND("^",B2)+1,LEN(B2))
It produces SMITH/MIKE as it should.  However, when I change the blank space in the first FIND to the "^",(to try to find the data between the 2 ^^), it does not produce a value.  I am not looking to use the blank space, just the name between the 2 ^^.  Headscratcher

Comment: @The_BK_Man you have selected an answer so why ask me?

Comment: I am not familiar with the protocol here.  That answer that I "checked" works but there was a better one.  In the future, should I just post the question in the "ANSWER YOUR QUESTION" field?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
MID(A1,FIND("%B",A1)+2,FIND("^",A1)-FIND("%B",A1)-2)
```